# Getting partial view fragments with Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring MVC, I just started my first project and I'm doing some research to be sure to set it up in a proper way (should work in the long-term!).

I already know that for a part of the project, I will need to manually change small fragments of the page through Ajax. I know it's possible to change part of the page (using Tiles). What I really need, though, is for example to change a single line in a table containing dynamically generated data (i.e. data coming from the database).

Can you suggest anything?

I don't want to use JSF or Spring JS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two choices:

- render on the server, send the update html snippet to the brower and use JavaScript to replace them
- send an AJAX request to the server, but this time return only the data (JSON) and the "render" the table line in the browser (or just update some pices of text)

For the fist choice you need a dedicated jsp file (and tiles configuration) to render only a single line. As fare as I know, there is no technical support.

What you can do, to reduce the amount of duplicated code is to use that single line rendering jsp in like in include in the one that renders the complete table.

Of course instead of using JSP to render the single line you can also use the Java Method that handles the request, and make it returning the html string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ralph. I want to take the first choice, rendering the Html on the server. But how can I render just a single row of a table?

Comment: @satoshi: there is less support than you may hoped. -- see my extended answer.

Comment: Thank you, Ralph. This is what I thought but I was thinking that maybe there is some framework to simplify this process (Tapestry, Play, Struts, Wicket, Stripes, ...)?

Comment: Ah: I did not take them in account, because the question was tagged with spring-mvc. But to my understanding you will have the same problem with all command base frameworks. You should have a closer look at Component Based Web Frameworks/Technology (like JSF, but you excluded it explicite)